Rambam’s source for crown of Priesthood
In Mishnei Torah Hilchot Talmud Torah  chapter 3 Halacha 1 the Rambam writes:

בִּשְׁלשָׁה כְּתָרִים נִכְתְּרוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל. כֶּתֶר תּוֹרָה וְכֶתֶר
כְּהֻנָּה וְכֶתֶר מַלְכוּת. כֶּתֶר כְּהֻנָּה זָכָה בּוֹ אַהֲרֹן
שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר כה יג) "וְהָיְתָה לּוֹ וּלְזַרְעוֹ אַחֲרָיו בְּרִית
כְּהֻנַּת עוֹלָם".
Three crowns were conferred upon Israel: the crown of Torah, the crown
of priesthood, and the crown of royalty. Aaron merited the crown of
priesthood, as [Numbers 25:13] states: "And it will be an eternal
covenant of priesthood for him and his descendants after him."

If we look at the verse the Rambam is quoting, it’s in reference to Pinchas getting priesthood because of his zealous action, nothing to do with Aaron getting priesthood. So why is the Rambam taking a verse from Pinchas instead of taking a pasuk from Shemot when Hashem gave Aaron priesthood to prove how Aaron got priesthood!?
The verse should have been taken from 40:15.

וּמָשַׁחְתָּ אֹתָם כַּאֲשֶׁר מָשַׁחְתָּ אֶת אֲבִיהֶם וְכִהֲנוּ לִי
וְהָיְתָה לִהְיֹת לָהֶם מׇשְׁחָתָם לִכְהֻנַּת עוֹלָם לְדֹרֹתָם.

Note that the Rambam is taking this from Avot DeRebbi Natan (41:1), so even if you want to answer that the Rambam always brings the most clear verse and that’s why he used Pinchas,  the question still stands to Avot DeRebbi Natan as to why this specific verse on Pinchas is being applied to Aaron

Does it say anywhere else that it's hereditary?

I agree it’s not as explicit but 40:15. וּמָשַׁחְתָּ אֹתָם כַּאֲשֶׁר מָשַׁחְתָּ אֶת אֲבִיהֶם וְכִהֲנוּ לִי וְהָיְתָה לִהְיֹת לָהֶם מׇשְׁחָתָם לִכְהֻנַּת עוֹלָם לְדֹרֹתָם.

similar, why do we quote passuk from pesach sheni "על מצות ומרורים יאכלוהו" for korech in the haggadah. i've once heard that we use the simplest verse that fits in this context instead of the correct one that needs an explanation to understand

Thanks @Mordechai yes I’ve heard that too which is why I mentioned that for the Rambam, but I haven’t heard of the same principle for Avot DeRebbi Natan which is why I said that even if you answer this for Rambam what would you answer for Avot DeRebbi Natan who seemingly does not hold by this same principle

the haggadah was written around the same time. should apply there too

Based on רבינו בחיי, Malbim, Chasam Sofer and Chizkuni on the posuk you quoted:
הָ֤יְתָה לּוֹ֙ וּלְזַרְע֣וֹ אַחֲרָ֔יו בְּרִ֖ית כְּהֻנַּ֣ת עוֹלָ֑ם תַּ֗חַת אֲשֶׁ֤ר קִנֵּא֙ לֵֽאלֹהָ֔יו וַיְכַפֵּ֖ר עַל־בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃‏
It seems that the Crown of Priesthood refers specifically to the Kohen Gadol - the High Priest.
Thus when the Rambam (and the Avot DeRebbi Natan(*)) state:

כֶּתֶר כְּהֻנָּה זָכָה בּוֹ אַהֲרֹן שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וְהָיְתָה לּוֹ וּלְזַרְעוֹ אַחֲרָיו בְּרִית כְּהֻנַּת עוֹלָם".‏

we interpret it as saying "The High Priesthood was given to Aaron - and mostly to Pinchas and his descendants - as we learn from this verse which confers on Pinchas the covenant of the High Priesthood forever."
So when you ask: "why this specific verse on Pinchas is being applied to Aaron"?
The answer seems to be that the High Priesthood promised to Aaron was mostly applied to Pinchas and his descendants.

(*) The אבות דרבי נתן actually says:

רבי שמעון אומר ג׳ כתרים הם אלו הן כתר תורה וכתר כהונה וכתר מלכות וכתר שם טוב עולה על גביהן. כתר כהונה כיצד אפילו נותן (לו) כל כסף וזהב שבעולם אין נותנין לו כתר כהונה שנא׳ (במדבר כה) והיתה לו ולזרעו אחריו ברית כהונת עולם.‏

Which could be applied to the High Priesthood as well.

Thank you very much for your answer. I certainly see where you are coming from and tempted to be satisfied with it but it is still troubling to me since when Aharon was ordained it was to him and his direct children and any of their future children… so by this the Priesthood by technicality was never supposed to be through Pinchas but now because of his actions he gained it, separate from the promise that Aharon got…therefore I find it hard to say this because the High Priesthood promised to Aharon could only be through who was originally promised which did not include Pinchas

Your trying to suggest that the Priesthood promised to Aharon was mainly applied to Pinchas and his decadents but the original keter Kehuna and therefore promise did not include Pinchas which which is why I find it troubling. Would love to hear if you have any insight into this
